# How to dynamically change background color of ios statusbar within webapp

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios, iphone

```js
let 
  body = document.querySelector( 'body' ),
  one = document.getElementById( 'one' ),
  three = document.getElementById( 'three' );

function colorBackground() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = '#0bb';
}
function removeBackground() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
}

one
  .addEventListener( 'mouseover', colorBackground );

one
  .addEventListener( 'mouseout', removeBackground );

three
  .addEventListener( 'mouseover', colorBackground );

three
  .addEventListener( 'mouseout', removeBackground );
```

```css
html, body, nav, div {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
html, div {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #eee; color: #444;
  user-select: none;
}
body {
  filter: brightness( 103.75% );
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
nav, div {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}
div {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; cursor: pointer;
}
div:hover {
  background-color: #0bb; color: #eee;
}
div:active {
  filter: brightness( 0% );
}
p {
  margin: auto; text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media( orientation: landscape ) {
  nav, div {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='us-EN' ontouchstart>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta 
      name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
    >
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/base.css'>
    <title>trifold</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div id='one'>
        <p>one</p>
      </div>
      <div id='two'>
        <p>two</p>
      </div>
      <div id='three'>
        <p>three</p>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src='js/origin.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When *"one"* or *"three"* is tapped/hovered the `body` background color changes to match. It's easier to see this effect happening when the buttons are scaled smaller and don't stretch the space of the full page. View an example of this effect in the second snippet below:

( hover over *'one'* or *'three'* and notice the background change ):

```js
let 
  body = document.querySelector( 'body' ),
  one = document.getElementById( 'one' ),
  three = document.getElementById( 'three' );

function colorBackground() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = '#0bb';
}
function removeBackground() {
  body.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
}

one
  .addEventListener( 'mouseover', colorBackground );

one
  .addEventListener( 'mouseout', removeBackground );

three
  .addEventListener( 'mouseover', colorBackground );

three
  .addEventListener( 'mouseout', removeBackground );
```

```css
html, body, nav, div {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
html, div {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #eee; color: #444;
  user-select: none;
}
body {
  filter: brightness( 103.75% );
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
nav, div {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column; transform: scale( 0.9 ); /*added transform*/
}
div {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; cursor: pointer;
}
div:hover {
  background-color: #0bb; color: #eee;
}
div:active {
  filter: brightness( 0% );
}
p {
  margin: auto; text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media( orientation: landscape ) {
  nav, div {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='us-EN' ontouchstart>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta 
      name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
    >
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/base.css'>
    <title>trifold</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div id='one'>
        <p>one</p>
      </div>
      <div id='two'>
        <p>two</p>
      </div>
      <div id='three'>
        <p>three</p>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src='js/origin.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Specifically within IOS on iphone this behavior is not working within the statusbar area of the screen. The statusbar background color does not change on iphone when one of the three buttons is tapped.

[image]

Using javaScript I'm forcing the websites background color to change.

```
one
  .addEventListener( 'mouseover', colorBackground );

one
  .addEventListener( 'mouseout', removeBackground );
```

However the ios statusbar ( the very top of the gif with the battery and 5G signal icons ) remains the original `#eee` background color when the *'one'* button is tapped.

Link to live website for iphone testing: https://user-railcoil.github.io/so/statusbar

### Objective: Is there a way to force the status bar color on iPhone to update with the rest of the background using vanilla JS?

Below is an image of the desired result when top div/button is tapped on iphone ( notice the status bar background color has changed to blue ).

[image]

*Edit: Even more strange is that the color of the statusbar background *does* change on IOS but only after a button is tapped **and** the phone is rotated into landscape mode after. Something about rotating the screen seems to force the color to get immediately updated.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One solution is setting the `theme-color` with JavaScript on a `meta` tag.

`<meta name="theme-color" content='#0dd'>`

[working example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7zowQ.gif)

```js
function colorBackground() {
  html.style.display = 'none';
  html.style.display = 'block';
  body.style.backgroundColor = '#0bb';
  head.innerHTML = 
    `
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta 
      name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
    >
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#0bb">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/base.css'>
    <title>trifold</title>         
    `; 
}
function removeBackground() {
  html.style.display = 'none';
  html.style.display = 'block';
  body.style.backgroundColor = '#eee';
  head.innerHTML = 
    `
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta 
      name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
    >
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#eee">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/base.css'>
    <title>trifold</title>         
    `; 
}
```

```css
html, body, nav, div {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%; width: 100%;
}
html, div {
  font-family: Arial;
  background-color: #eee; color: #444;
  user-select: none;
}
body {
  filter: brightness( 103.75% );
  font-size:1.5rem;
}
nav, div {
  display: flex; flex-direction: column;
}
div {
  outline: 1px solid #ddd; cursor: pointer;
}
div:hover {
  background-color: #0bb; color: #eee;
}
div:active {
  filter: brightness( 0% );
}
p {
  margin: auto; text-transform: uppercase;
}
@media( orientation: landscape ) {
  nav, div {
    flex-direction: row;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='us-EN' ontouchstart>
  <head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8'>
    <meta 
      name='viewport'
      content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'
    >
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/base.css'>
    <title>trifold</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav>
      <div id='one'>
        <p>one</p>
      </div>
      <div id='two'>
        <p>two</p>
      </div>
      <div id='three'>
        <p>three</p>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <script src='js/origin.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the status bar background color, you can simply change the meta tag:

```js
document
  .querySelector('meta[name="theme-color"]')
    .setAttribute('content', '#F2F0ED');
```